# SQL insert into query logic issue

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I was wondering if someone could take a quick look at the SQL query which i am trying to write which basically takes three tables, links them and pastes values into a table that I created called tblSearchEngine01.  As you can probably understand, i generated the code by using an MS Access Query (which worked) but for some reason, upon writing it in SQL, it doesnt work anymore.  The issue seems to be on the SELECT string.

I was wondering if someone could take a peak to see if there is some high level issue or logic that I am missing and therefore causing me this issue. I have looked at all the tables and fields listed and there seems to be no problems. Perhaps my spaces are causing an issue??

Thanks,
A

```
st_sql = "INSERT INTO tblSearchEngine01 ([ID Event], [ID Project], [ID_Project_Phase], [Owner],[Contact], [Event], [Type], [Participant], [Role_type], [Commitment], [Description], [Identification_status], [Overall_status], [Status], [tblMasterListOfEventsNotes], [tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes], [Automatic user entry], [Automatic date of entry]," & _
            "[Automatic_user_entry], [Automatic_date_of_entry], [Expected start date], [Actual start date], [Expected completion date], [Actual completion date], [Effective date], [Priority])"

            "SELECT [tblMasterListOfEvents].[ID Event], [tblMasterListOfEvents].[ID Project],  [tblMasterListOfEvents].[ID_Project_Phase], [tblMasterListOfEvents].[Owner], [tblMasterListOfEventsHistory].[Contact], [tblMasterListOfEvents].[Event], [tblMasterListOfEventsHistory].[Type], [tblProjManagementPhaseParticipants].[Participant]" & _
            "[tblProjManagementPhaseParticipants].[Role_type], [tblMasterListOfEvents].[Commitment], [tblMasterListOfEventsHistory].[Description], [tblMasterListOfEvents].[Identification_status], [tblMasterListOfEvents].[Overall_status], [tblMasterListOfEventsHistory].[Status], [tblMasterListOfEvents].[Notes]" & _
             "[tblMasterListOfEventsHistory].[Notes], [tblMasterListOfEvents].[Automatic user entry], [tblMasterListOfEvents].[Automatic date of entry], [tblMasterListOfEventsHistory].[Automatic_user_entry], [tblMasterListOfEventsHistory].[Automatic_date_of_entry], [tblMasterListOfEvents].[Expected start date], [tblMasterListOfEvents].[Actual start date]" & _
             "[tblMasterListOfEvents].[Expected completion date], [tblMasterListOfEvents].[Actual completion date], [tblMasterListOfEventsHistory].[Effective date], [tblMasterListOfEvents].[Priority]" & _

        "FROM tblMasterListOfEvents INNER JOIN tblProjManagementPhaseParticipants ON tblMasterListOfEvents.[ID Event] = tblProjManagementPhaseParticipants.ID_Event)" & _
        "INNER JOIN tblMasterListOfEventsHistory ON tblMasterListOfEvents.[ID Event] = tblMasterListOfEventsHistory.ID_Event"
```

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, you seem to be missing commas  - e.g. after [Participant] and [Actual start date] (also notes?). I found [this site](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) quite handy for this sort of thing.

```
INSERT INTO tblsearchengine01 
        ([id event], 
         [id project], 
         [id_project_phase], 
         [owner], 
         [contact], 
         [event], 
         [type], 
         [participant], 
         [role_type], 
         [commitment], 
         [description], 
         [identification_status], 
         [overall_status], 
         [status], 
         [tblmasterlistofeventsnotes], 
         [tblmasterlistofeventshistorynotes], 
         [automatic user entry], 
         [automatic date of entry], 
         [automatic_user_entry], 
         [automatic_date_of_entry], 
         [expected start date], 
         [actual start date], 
         [expected completion date], 
         [actual completion date], 
         [effective date], 
         [priority]) 
SELECT [tblmasterlistofevents].[id event], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[id project], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[id_project_phase], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[owner], 
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[contact], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[event], 
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[type], 
   [tblprojmanagementphaseparticipants].[participant], 
   [tblprojmanagementphaseparticipants].[role_type], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[commitment], 
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[description], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[identification_status], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[overall_status], 
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[status], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[notes], 
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[notes], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[automatic user entry], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[automatic date of entry], 
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[automatic_user_entry], 
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[automatic_date_of_entry], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[expected start date], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[actual start date], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[expected completion date], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[actual completion date], 
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[effective date], 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[priority] 
FROM   tblmasterlistofevents 
   INNER JOIN tblprojmanagementphaseparticipants 
           ON tblmasterlistofevents.[id event] = 
              tblprojmanagementphaseparticipants.id_event 
   INNER JOIN tblmasterlistofeventshistory 
           ON tblmasterlistofevents.[id event] = 
              tblmasterlistofeventshistory.id_event
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.  Let me take a look..  by clause you mean "where" ??

Comment: By the way, i put all the commas in but still no luck.. From the "SELECT" line down, all is red :(

Comment: There is a spurious `)` after `ID_Event` in the first inner join. What IDE/language are you using. It is really helpful to format your sql in a readable way (see answer). Does you IDE/language support strings running over multiple lines?

Comment: OK, the answer above is a big help and i no longer have all the red lines.  Upon executing the query however, i now have run time error 3075 - syntax error (missing operator)..   I need some time to review to see what could be off...  I will let you know..   PS- sorry, i am not familiar with the term IDE Language or multiple lines...  Sorry i still have a lot to learn